# Chain complexes as functors and chain morphisms as natural transformations

Tags: category-theory

**Definition** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be any category. A graded object in $\mathcal{C}$ is a sequence $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ or, equivalently, a functor $C:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathcal{C}$, where the group of integers is considered as a discrete category. A graded morphism $f:A\to B$ of degree $k$ from a graded object $A$ to a graded object $B$ is a collection $(f_n:A_n\to B_{n+k})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$. Thai is to say, $f$ is a natural transformation from $A$ to $B\circ s^k$, where $s:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ sends $n$ to $n+1$. Of course, a morphism $f:A\to B$ of degree $k$ composes with a morphism $g:B\to C$ of degree $l$ to a morphism $g\circ f:A\to C$ of degree $k+l$. Graded objects in $\mathcal{C}$ and morphisms between them form a category we will denote by $\operatorname{Gr}(\mathcal{C})$.

**Definition** Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be a pointed category and let $0$ be the constant graded object $(0)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$. We shall also write $0$ for any morphism (of whichever degree) that factors through $0$. A chain complex $(C,d)$ in $\mathcal{C}$ is a graded object $C$, together with a morphism $d:C\to C$ of degree $-1$ (its differential) such that $d\circ d=0$. A chain morphism $f:(C,d)\to (C',d')$ is a morphism $f:C\to C'$ of degree $0$ such that $d'\circ f=f\circ d'$. Chain complexes in $\mathcal{C}$ and their chain morphisms form a category we will denote by $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathcal{C})$.

I want to view chain complexes as functors. The only thing I could say was this. Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as a poset category, where $m\geq n$ means there exists exactly one morphism from $m$ to $n$. Then consider the functor category $\operatorname{Funct}(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{C})$. Then the category $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathcal{C})$ is the full subcategory of  $\operatorname{Funct}(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{C})$ with the property that $d_n\circ d_{n+1}=0$ for each $n$.

First question: is it correct what I said in the last few lines?

Other ideas I had, but I couldn't formalize, were: since differentials $d$ of chain complexes are themselves graded morphisms of degree $-1$, maybe I can define a chain complex as a functor on $\mathbb{Z}$ to the category $\operatorname{Gr}(\mathcal{C})$ of graded objects in $\mathcal{C}$. Here the main problem for me was that, if to an integer $n$ I associate a pair $(C,d)$, then I don't know what to associate to each morphism in $\mathbb{Z}$ coming from the order relation $\geq$. Probably this approach is wrong.

Last approach I am trying to formalize was the one consisting in using the arrow category of $\mathcal{C}$ or of $\operatorname{Gr}(\mathcal{C})$, but again I am stuck and don't know how to proceed. For instance, I consider the category $\operatorname{Arr}(\operatorname{Gr(\mathcal{C})})$. An object here is a graded morphism. Then I take the full subcategory of graded endomorphisms of degree $-1$ with the property that any two of them compose to the zero morphisms. Do you have any suggestion or just comments?